# Why ASP.NET website is asking credentials for some users?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, windows-authentication

My website is hosted in remote server with Windows Authentication enabled. I and some of my colleges were able to access the website. But for some peoples it's prompting for credentials. I've done some modifications didn't remembered to access the website. Is there any group/user need to be added in AD?

Please help me on this. I'm struggling since 2 days.

Comment: are any of those users using Internet Explorer? What are their Content Zone settings for NTLM/Kerberos? By “remote” is this over the Internet or in a LAN?

Comment: The prompt is purely a browser side setting, (for IE https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password), so it is perfectly normal that some people see it due to their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IE has the security setting which will send the current login in windows user name and password automatically. If your client doesn't enable the auto send username and password, it will prompt for credentials.

More details about how to enable it, you could refer to below steps:

1.Open the IE and find the internet options.

[image]

2.Modify the user authentication

[image]